# Tor may be missing or inaccessible

Tags: tor

this was my installation of tor that resulted in the error message **Tor may be missing or inaccessible**

```
sudo wget https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/8.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.2_en-US.tar.xz

sudo tar xvf  tor-browser-linux64-8.0.2_en-US.tar.xz

sudo chmod 775 tor-browser_en-US tor-browser_en-US/Browser tor-browser_en-US/Browser/*

cd tor-browser_en-US/Browser

./start-tor-browser

Your Tor Browser profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

Here's my ls -l /tor-browser_en-US/Browser

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    13504 Dec 31  1999 abicheck
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      440 Dec 31  1999 application.ini
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 browser
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root        0 Dec 31  1999 chrome.manifest
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 defaults
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      157 Dec 31  1999 dependentlibs.list
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 dictionaries
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      279 Dec 31  1999 execdesktop
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      388 Dec 31  1999 firefox
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   207520 Dec 31  1999 firefox.real
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 fonts
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 gtk2
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 icons
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   526920 Dec 31  1999 libfreeblpriv3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    67992 Dec 31  1999 liblgpllibs.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  1801680 Dec 31  1999 libmozavcodec.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   236120 Dec 31  1999 libmozavutil.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root     6312 Dec 31  1999 libmozgtk.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   145856 Dec 31  1999 libmozsandbox.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   873432 Dec 31  1999 libmozsqlite3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   250824 Dec 31  1999 libnspr4.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   664392 Dec 31  1999 libnss3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   479136 Dec 31  1999 libnssckbi.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   145816 Dec 31  1999 libnssdbm3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   187104 Dec 31  1999 libnssutil3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    18784 Dec 31  1999 libplc4.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    14720 Dec 31  1999 libplds4.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   179208 Dec 31  1999 libsmime3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   269896 Dec 31  1999 libsoftokn3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   343208 Dec 31  1999 libssl3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 95988776 Dec 31  1999 libxul.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  5283068 Dec 31  1999 omni.ja
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  2225136 Dec 31  1999 pingsender
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root       48 Dec 31  1999 platform.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   203352 Dec 31  1999 plugin-container
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   100530 Dec 31  1999 precomplete
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root        0 Dec 31  1999 removed-files
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    12791 Oct 14 16:34 start-tor-browser
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root     1682 Dec 31  1999 start-tor-browser.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root     2422 Oct 14 16:09 sudo
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root       82 Dec 31  1999 tbb_version.json
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root     4096 Dec 31  1999 TorBrowser
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   177592 Dec 31  1999 updater
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      689 Dec 31  1999 updater.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      138 Dec 31  1999 update-settings.ini
```

**THIS QUESTION IS NOT OFF TOPIC**: it runs on Kali Linux just fine but Ubuntu it doesn't this is distribution related

Answer (score 2):

Tor Browser (*torbrowser-launcher*) is available in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. torbrowser-launcher handles downloading the most recent version of Tor Browser Bundle for you, in your language and for your architecture. After installing Tor Browser, it can be launched by searching for *tor* in the Dash and clicking the Tor Browser icon. The Tor Browser Launcher Settings app is also installed along with Tor Browser.

[image: Tor]

---

Unfortunately the Tor Browser developers change their signing key that is used to install Tor Browser at periodic intervals which makes the torbrowser-launcher package from the default Ubuntu repositories not work because it is not as up-to-date as the current version of Tor Browser.

These are the instructions from the official [Tor Browser User Manual](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/) in case the Ubuntu torbrowser-launcher package hasn't updated the gpg key that is required to install Tor Browser. When I updated the Tor Browser Developers signing key I noticed that the key that I updated will expire in less than one year.

#### Install Tor Browser

1. Navigate to the Tor Browser [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download).
2. Download the GNU/Linux .tar.xz file
3. (Recommended) Verify the file's signature. The steps for verifying the file's signature are shown below.
4. When the download is complete, extract the archive with the command `tar -xf [TB archive]` or with the Archive Manager.
5. Navigate to the newly extracted Tor Browser directory. Right-click on *start-tor-browser.desktop*, open *Properties* and change the permission to *Allow executing file as program* by clicking the checkbox.
6. Start Tor Browser from the command line by running:

   ```
    ./start-tor-browser
   ```

---

#### Set a keyboard shortcut to start Tor Browser

Remember the location where you downloaded the tor-browser-linux64-xx.x.xx_xx-xx.tar.xz archive. In this example I will call this location `/home/your-username/Downloads/` which is the default location of the Downloads directory in Ubuntu if you replace `your-username` by your own user name.

Remember the directory where you extracted the Tor Browser files. In this example I will call this directory `/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/` where en is the abbreviation for the language and US is the abbreviation for the nation which could be different depending on your language and nation.

Go to Settings -> *Keyboard* -> *View and Customize Shortcuts* -> *Set Custom Shortcut*.

- In the field after Name type *Tor Browser*.
- In the field after Command type: `sh -c '"/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k`
- In order to fill in an entry in the field after Shortcut press any easy to remember keyboard shortcut combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd>).

[image]

Now you can start Tor Browser by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd>.

---

#### How to verify Tor Browser's signature

**Fetching the Tor Developers key**

The Tor Browser team signs Tor Browser releases. Import the Tor Browser Developers signing key (0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290):

```
gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
```

This should show you something like:

```
gpg: key 4E2C6E8793298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
pub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [C] [expires: 2020-08-24]
      EF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
uid           [ unknown] Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>
sub   rsa4096 2018-05-26 [S] [expires: 2020-09-12]
```

After importing the key, you can save it to a file (identifying it by fingerprint here):

```
gpg --output ./tor.keyring --export 0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
```

**Verifying the signature**

To verify the signature of the package you downloaded, you will need to download the corresponding ".asc" signature file as well as the installer file itself, and verify it with a command that asks GnuPG to verify the file that you downloaded.

The example below assumes that you downloaded these two files to your Downloads folder.

```
gpgv --keyring ./tor.keyring ~/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-9.0_en-US.tar.xz{.asc,}
```

The result of the command should produce something like this:

```
gpgv: Signature made 07/08/19 04:03:49 Pacific Daylight Time
gpgv:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpgv: Good signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>"
```

Answer (score 0):

When i downloaded **Tor** that it didn't set any permissions on the profile file or many of the others, so i had to manually run

```
sudo chmod 775 /Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profiles.ini

sudo chmod -R 775 /Browser/
```

After this ./start-tor-browser was able to start